# Export/import dataframe as Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an example from the pandas documentation site and can't get it run. Export as excel file works well, but the following import not:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=list("ABCD")) 
df = df.cumsum()     

df.to_excel("/tmp/foo.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1") 

print("Reading data back from an excel file")
df2=pd.read_excel("/tmp/foo.xlsx", "Sheet1", index_col=None, na_values=["NA"])
#print(df2)
```

my error message:

```
python3 /tmp/downloads/tmp_358/main.py
Reading data back from an excel file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/downloads/tmp_358/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    df2=pd.read_excel("/tmp/foo.xlsx", "Sheet1", index_col=None, na_values=["NA"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 37, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 170, in open_workbook
    raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

Python 3.6.9 and pandas==1.1.4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
df.to_excel("/tmp/foo.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1", engine='openpyxl')
df2=pd.read_excel("/tmp/foo.xlsx", "Sheet1", index_col=None, na_values=["NA"], engine='openpyxl')
```